# Calling hasMany Relationship with json in blade view

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

I have a model name Devisi with a HaMany relationship.

```
class Divisi extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'perlengkapan_id'
    ];

    public function setPerlengkapanIdAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['perlengkapan_id'] = json_encode($value, JSON_UNESCAPED_LINE_TERMINATORS);
    }
    
    public function getPerlengkapanIdAttribute($value)
    {
       return $this->attributes['perlengkapan_id[]'] = json_decode($value, true);
    }

    public function Perlengkapan()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Perlengkapan::class);
    }
}
```

**And I Have Model Perlengkapan With Belongs To**

```
class Perlengkapan extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'divisi_id'
    ];

    public function Divisi()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Divisi::class);
    }
}
```

**This Devisi Controller**

```
public function index()
{
    $devisi = Divisi::with('perlengkapan')->get();

    return view('admin.devisi.index', ['data' => $devisi]);
}
```

**In View Blade**

```
 @forelse ($data as $i)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ $no++ }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $i->name }}</td>
                    @forelse ($i->perlengkapan as $item)
                        <td>{{ $i['name']}}</td>
                    @empty
                        <td>Data Kosong</td>
                    @endforelse
                </tr>
            @empty
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3" class="text-center">Data Kosong</td>
                </tr>
            @endforelse
```

I need to call json tabel with relationship has many to blade view, but I try this still error.
Data perlengkapan['name] is still blank, not showing data; how can I call data?

Comment: Change your $i['name'] to $item['name']

Comment: but still not showing data

Comment: Can you dd your $devisi and check see whether is there perlengkapan data ?

Comment: #relations: array:1 [▼
        "perlengkapan" => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1296 ▼
          #items: []
          #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
        }
      ]

Comment: In Divisi , change to
return $this->hasMany('App\Perlengkapan','divisi_id','divisi_id');

In Perlengkapan , change to
return $this->belongsTo('App\Divisi','divisi_id','divisi_id);

and try to dd again

Comment: yes it can, but i need to call data from perlengkapan not only one